# I have loads of extra space coming from nowhere

Tags: html, css

I have a few pictures lined up together using html and css. For some reason I am getting loads of extra empty space after the container div when it shouldn't. I would really appreciate some help!

This project is currently hosted live and can be found here: [My Project](http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#mixtape {
  -ms-zoom: 0.25;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
}
#case {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#shadow {
  position: relative;
  top: -836px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#disk1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -1548px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: disk 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#disk2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -1548px;
  left: 255px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: disk 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
@keyframes disk {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mixtape</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--ubuntu font-->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mixtape">
    <img src="case.svg" id="case">
    <img src="shadow.svg" id="shadow">
    <img src="disk.svg" id="disk1">
    <img src="disk.svg" id="disk2">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to be? 

_-webkit-transform-origin: center top;_

In your CSS, it is exactly what it happens

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of strange rendering of SVGs if they are placed in  tags. I would recommend trying inline SVG instead with fixed size.
Right now it's behaving like an img tag but preserving the space as for full size svg.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed to work fine when I pasted it in jsfiddle, so perhaps there is something else having an effect.

Nevertheless, I have made a few changes that may help:

1) Position the `#mixtape` relative and then its children absolute (absolute to its parent).

2) I added a `.disk` class to DRY your code since there are 2 disks and only the `top` and `left` properties differ.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#mixtape {
  -ms-zoom: 0.25;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
#case {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.disk {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: disk 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#disk1 {
  top: 146px;
  left: 151px;
}
#disk2 {
  top: 146px;
  left: 734px;
}
@keyframes disk {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mixtape">
    <img src="http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/case.svg" id="case">
    <img src="http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/shadow.svg" id="shadow">
    <img src="http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/disk.svg" class="disk" id="disk1">
    <img src="http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/disk.svg" class="disk" id="disk2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks everyone for the responses! So after setting the position of all elements contained within the #mixtape Div the #mixtape is no longer centered. Neither margin:auto nor text-align:centered is doing the trick, any ideas?

Comment: Hey @MikePeterson I have edited my answer. I have changed the #mixtape and added: display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;

Comment: @MikePeterson also if my solution worked for you would you mind accepting as the answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting position relative on the inner elements.  Try setting position relative to the outer div, and then setting all of the other elements to position: absolute.

Position relative is normally used to contain elements within it that are positioned.

When an element is normally absolutely positioned.  It is positioned within the entire page.

If that element is inside of a relative element.  It will be positioned within that element.

That will solve your space problem.

As to WHY it's creating so much space.  Is the same as the answer above.  The SVG is rendering in a manner that the dom detects it at a specific height.  Thus it "makes room" for that height.

If you look at your page here:
http://mkitgreat.com/mixtape/case.svg

Look at how big that is.  Compared to what you have rendering in the page.  It would be smart to change the image size.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to everyone who posted an answer!

By setting the contained elements' position to be absolute to the parent as opposed to being relative I was able to eliminate the extra white-space:

```
#case{
    position:absolute;
    ...
```

I was also able to center the entire mixtape by setting the transform origin to be centered:

```
#mixtape{   
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
    ...
```